# How to connect remote docker instance using Pulumi?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, pulumi

I have created VM instance in GCP using pulumi and installed docker. And I am trying to connect remote instance of the docker but its getting failed to due to connection establishment (asking for a key verification in a pop up window).

```js
const remoteInstance = new docker.Provider(
  "remote",
  {
    host: interpolate`ssh://user@${externalIP}:22`,
  },
  { dependsOn: dockerInstallation }
);
```

I can able to run docker containers locally. But want to run the same in VM. The **code snippet** is [here](https://gist.github.com/madhank93/f65bf5119424f91aea23d4abf7dee653)

Comment: It'd be helpful to share the entire code, including how you started the VM and bootstrapped Docker

Comment: @jaxxstorm here is the code [gist](https://gist.github.com/madhank93/f65bf5119424f91aea23d4abf7dee653)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with the recent version of `"@pulumi/docker": "^3.2.0"` you can now pass the ssh options. [Reference](https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi/discussions/9010#discussioncomment-2215096)

```js
const remoteInstance = new docker.Provider(
  "remote",
  {
    host: interpolate`ssh://user@${externalIP}:22`,
    sshOpts: [
      "-o",
      "StrictHostKeyChecking=no",
      "-o",
      "UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null",
    ],
  },
  { dependsOn: dockerInstallation }
);
```